# Transfer file from PC to other device via Bluetooth code example C++

Tags: c++, bluetooth

Hi Stackoverflow Users !!!

**Questions:**

1. **I am looking for some code examples which show how can I find Bluetooth devices that are connected to my computer.**
2. **I am looking for some code examples which show how can I  transfer information from my computer to a mobile device.**

Now I am trying to develop application on C++ which must work with [**Bluetooth**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) devices. While I was researching through the internet I found some information about Bluetooth and found some code examples which present how to work with Bluetooth devices. For example, [**here**](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2051.htm) I found code which indicates how to find all bluetooth devices within range of all bluetooth radios:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <bthdef.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Irprops.lib")

// The BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS structure facilitates 
// enumerating installed Bluetooth radios.
BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS)
};

// The BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO structure contains information
// about a Bluetooth radio.
BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO),
  0,
};

// The BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS structure specifies
// search criteria for Bluetooth device searches.
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
  1,
  0,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  15,
  NULL
};

// The BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO structure provides information
// about a Bluetooth device.
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO),
  0,
};

HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **args) {
  while(true) {
    // The BluetoothFindFirstRadio function begins the 
    // enumeration of local Bluetooth radios.
    m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);

    int m_radio_id = 0;
    do {
      m_radio_id++;

      // The BluetoothGetRadioInfo function obtains information
      // about a Bluetooth radio.
      BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);

      wprintf(L"Radio %d:\r\n", m_radio_id);
      wprintf(L"\tName: %s\r\n", m_bt_info.szName);
      wprintf(L"\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[1], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[0], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[2], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[3], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[4], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[5]);
      wprintf(L"\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_bt_info.ulClassofDevice);
      wprintf(L"\tManufacturer: 0x%04x\r\n", m_bt_info.manufacturer);

      m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;

      ::ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
      m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

      m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

      int m_device_id = 0;
      do {
        m_device_id++;

        wprintf(L"\tDevice %d:\r\n", m_device_id);
        wprintf(L"\t\tName: %s\r\n", m_device_info.szName);
        wprintf(L"\t\tAddress: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5]);
        wprintf(L"\t\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_device_info.ulClassofDevice);
        wprintf(L"\t\tConnected: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fConnected ? L"true" : L"false");
        wprintf(L"\t\tAuthenticated: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fAuthenticated ? L"true" : L"false");
        wprintf(L"\t\tRemembered: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fRemembered ? L"true" : L"false");

      } while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));

      BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);

    } while(BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));

    BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);

    Sleep(10000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I created a project and ran it on my notebook with Bluetooth enabled, but no results appeared, just as if the application couldn't find any Bluetooth device. After I continued my research and found other article called [**Finding Bluetooth devices and services using C++ in Windows XP**](http://www.miniware.net/articles/viewarticle.php?id=19)

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "irprops.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //Initialising winsock

    WSADATA data;
    int result;

    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);//initializing winsock

    if (result!=0) {
        cout << "An error occured while initialising winsock, closing....";
        exit(result);
    }

    //Initialising query for device
    WSAQUERYSET queryset;

    memset(&queryset, 0, sizeof(WSAQUERYSET));
    queryset.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    queryset.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;

    HANDLE hLookup;

    result = WSALookupServiceBegin(&queryset, LUP_CONTAINERS, &hLookup);

    if (result!=0){
        cout << "An error occured while initialising look for devices, closing....";
        Sleep(100000);
        exit(result);
    }

    //Initialisation succedd, start looking for devices

    BYTE buffer[4096];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    DWORD bufferLength = sizeof(buffer);
    WSAQUERYSET *pResults = (WSAQUERYSET*)&buffer;

        while (result==0){
            result = WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE,&bufferLength, pResults);

            if(result==0){// A device found
                //print the name of the device
                LPTSTR s = pResults->lpszServiceInstanceName;
                wcout << s << "found. quering for services\n";
                //Initialise quering the device services
                WSAQUERYSET queryset2;
                memset(&queryset2, 0, sizeof(queryset2));
                queryset2.dwSize = sizeof(queryset2);
                queryset2.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
                queryset2.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 0;
                CSADDR_INFO * addr = (CSADDR_INFO *)pResults->lpcsaBuffer;
                WCHAR addressAsString[1000];
                DWORD addressSize = sizeof(addressAsString);
                WSAAddressToString(addr->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr,addr->RemoteAddr.iSockaddrLength,NULL,addressAsString, &addressSize);
                queryset2.lpszContext = addressAsString;
                GUID protocol = L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID;
                queryset2.lpServiceClassId = &protocol;
                HANDLE hLookup2;
                int result2 = WSALookupServiceBegin(&queryset2, LUP_FLUSHCACHE |LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_COMMENT, &hLookup2);

                if (result2 !=0){
                    cout << "An error occured while initializing query for services";
                    Sleep(100000);
                    exit(result);
                }

                //Start quering for device services
                while(result2 ==0){
                    BYTE buffer2[4096];
                    memset(buffer2, 0, sizeof(buffer2));
                    DWORD bufferLength2 = sizeof(buffer2);
                    WSAQUERYSET *pResults2 = (WSAQUERYSET*)&buffer2;
                    result2 = WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup2,LUP_FLUSHCACHE |LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_COMMENT,&bufferLength2,pResults2);
                    if(result2 == 0)
                        wcout << "Service found: " << pResults2->lpszServiceInstanceName <<"\n";
                    Sleep(100000);
                }
            }
        }

        Sleep(100000);

    return 0;     

}
```

When I compile this one and launch application error message appears"**An error occurred while initializing look for devices, closing ......**"

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the specific error you get. That is, what is the returned result? It could help you narrow down a specific cause.

Comment: I want to know am I on a right way to make application ?? Or maybe you can get links !!! From where I must start my development ?

Comment: You might be on the right way. My point was that you get an error on the very first initialization. That is, the call " result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);". Obviously something went wrong there. Could you tell us what the value of "result" is after the call? If it's one of the values here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx ), you might have a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: Now I am trying on Windows 7 operation system ... may be that is result ??

Comment: Program exit from this part of code:result = WSALookupServiceBegin(&queryset, LUP_CONTAINERS, &hLookup);

    if (result!=0){
  cout << "An error occured while initialising look for devices, closing....";
  Sleep(100000);
  exit(result);
 }

Comment: I place this line int lastErrorResult = WSAGetLastError(); in the code and get error code 10108 - "Service not found. 
No such service is known. The service cannot be found in the specified name space."

Comment: is it possible that you have the default windows stack/driver loaded and running which is interfering with your app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check this [link](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4k.html),

It may be useful for you ... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I feel I have to answer it for the 8k people that viewed it afterwards.

The `queryset` structure was wrong, that's why `wsalookupbegin` failed

```
queryset.lpcsaBuffer = NULL;
```

Adding this to your struct could make it work; then use `wsalookupbegin` to return a handle; then pass the handle on the `wsalookupnext`, and you get the desired results depending on your flags.