# Android and Windows communication via Bluetooth

Tags: android, c++, c, windows, bluetooth

Can someone please help me find some proper tutorials or a sample code for sending and receiving data from a Windows C++ application via Bluetooth? I need this Windows application to communicate with an Android app. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818990/transfer-file-from-pc-to-other-device-via-bluetooth-code-example-c

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Windows Bluetooth API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).